# How to covert tuple to string in pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I have data as

```
id company
1  (a,b)
2  (a,c)
3  (f,g,h)
```

company is tuple, I generate it from `BagToTuple(sortedbag.company) AS company`.

I would like to remove the formate of tuple, I would like the data is looked as following:

```
id company
1  a b
2  a c
3  f g h
```

I would like the company column has no brackets and separate by space. Thanks.

===================update

I have the data set as

```
id company
1  a
1  b
1  a
2  c
2  a
```

I wrote the code as following:
record = load....

```
grp = GROUP record BY id; 

newdata = FOREACH grp GENERATE group AS id, 
        COUNT(record) AS counts, 
        BagToTuple(record.company) AS company;
```

The output is looks like:

```
id count company
1  3     (a,b,a)
2  2     (c,a)
```

But I would like company can be sorted and distinct, and no Brackets, and divide by space.
What I expect result is as following:

```
id count company
1  3     a b
2  2     a c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just replace BagToTuple with BagToString in the last step:

```
newdata2 = FOREACH grp 
GENERATE group AS id, COUNT(record) as counts, 
    BagToString(record.company, ' ') as company:chararray;

STORE newdata2 into outdir using PigStorage('#');
```

After the script runs

```
$ cat outdir2/part-r-00000
1#3#a b a
2#2#a c
```

Comment: thx. it for some reason I do not know change my code into Garbled and I do not know why.

Answer (score 1):

for general tuple to bag, if you don't want UDF, you can do BagToString(TOBAG( your tuple ))

Answer (score 0):

You can use the in-built FLATTEN() operator. http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#Flatten+Operator.

Comment: when I use flatten. there are new columns are created. I try to replace '\t' but it does not work.

Comment: Can you post the code here so that we can take a look?

Comment: already update. If I add flatten. The columns company will be divded into lots of columns.